# Android Billing Library V3

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

Maybe I'm doing something wrong but if so I can't figure it out. I'm attempting to purchase a product and for whatever reason the purchase process is working incorrectly. When I click to buy an item it gives me the billing process. Then after paying I have to click it again in order to receive the chips I purchased. Any help would be awesome, thanks! Here is a link to the tool if you're unfamiliar with it https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 and let me know if you need any more details.

```
    bp = new BillingProcessor(this, base64EncodedPublicKey,
            new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onProductPurchased(String productId,
                        TransactionDetails details) {
                    Log.v("chip", productId + " purchased");
                    if (bp.consumePurchase(productId)){
                        if(productId=="itemOne" || productId=="one_chip")
                            ChipUpdate.updateChipCount(2500);
                        if(productId=="itemTwo"|| productId=="five_chip")
                            ChipUpdate.updateChipCount(15000);
                        if(productId=="itemThree"|| productId=="ten_chip")
                            ChipUpdate.updateChipCount(35000);
                        if(productId=="itemFour"|| productId=="fifty_chip")
                            ChipUpdate.updateChipCount(200000);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
                    Log.v("chip", "Error code: " + errorCode);
                    Log.v("chip", "Error: " + error);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingInitialized() {
                    Log.v("chip", "billing initialized");
                    readyToPurchase = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
                    for (String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts())
                        Log.v("chip", "Owned Managed Product: " + sku);
                    for (String sku : bp.listOwnedSubscriptions())
                        Log.v("chip", "Owned Subscription: " + sku);
                }

            });
public void oneChip(String noVal) {
    Log.v("oneChip", "Calling launch purchase flow");
    bp.purchase(this, itemOne);
    Log.v("oneChip", "made it through launch purchase flow");
}

public void fiveChip(String noVal) {
    Log.v("fiveChip", "Calling launch purchase flow");
    bp.purchase(this, itemTwo);
    Log.v("fiveChip", "made it through launch purchase flow");
}

public void tenChip(String noVal) {
    Log.v("tenChip", "Calling launch purchase flow");
    bp.purchase(this, itemThree);
    Log.v("tenChip", "made it through launch purchase flow");
}

public void fiftyChip(String noVal) {
    Log.v("fiftyChip", "Calling launch purchase flow");
    bp.purchase(this, itemFour);
    Log.v("fiftyChip", "made it through launch purchase flow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should not call `consumePurchase` in `onProductPurchased`

Comment: I tried omitting it but I was getting an error where you could get unlimited chips after purchasing an item. I also tried moving the if statement and still no luck.

Comment: you should consume in the same method where you call `bp.purchase`,not in the billing callback

Comment: That's initially where I had the call. I figured out why it is happening, sort of. Here is a link to why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906980/in-app-billing-issue